# Why does this code work, given that the function needs to be compiled before echo statement?

Tags: php

I'm confused as to why this code works:

```
<?php
        echo fix_names("William" , "henry", "gatES");

        function fix_names($n1, $n2, $n3){
            $n1 = ucfirst(strtolower($n1));
            $n2 = ucfirst(strtolower($n2));
            $n3 = ucfirst(strtolower($n3));

            return $n1 . " " . $n2 . " " . $n3;
        }
      ?>
```

I thought the compiler passes through each line once, but the code above makes it so the code needs to compile the function first, then go back and process the echo statement.  Shouldn't the echo statement have to come AFTER the function?

Comment: No, the ___script___ needs to be ___compiled___ before being ___executed___. The compiler compiles the entire script file before it starts to execute it

Comment: I don't think compiler is the word you are looking for. Also, how would you expect objects to work if a script was run literally line by line?

Comment: @thatidiotguy - PHP is compiled; but I'm guessing that Gregg thinks it's interpreted (but is still using the wrong word)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought the compiler passes through each line once,

That's a gross oversimplification of what happens.

In order to execute your code, *statements* are generally run sequentially from top to bottom but, as you've seen, the introduction of function and class definitions renders this naive description flawed.

Definitions are interpreted, to some degree, before execution of your procedural code begins; they shall therefore be available — the rules of scope allowing — even in procedural code that's found above them.

[From the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php):

> Functions need not be defined before they are referenced, except when a function is conditionally defined as shown in the two examples below.

A further analysis would require an in-depth explanation of how PHP is interpreted, compiled and executed, and is beyond the scope of this site.